# How expensive is opening a HANDLE?

Tags: c, handle

I am currently writing a time-sensitive application, and it got me thinking: How expensive is opening/closing a handle (in my case a COM port) compared to reading/writing from the handle?

I know the relative cost of other operations (like dynamic allocation vs. stack allocation), but I haven't found anything in my travels about this.

Comment: What did your profiling experiments reveal?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an unique answer, specially in case of devices. In general, the "open" operation (CreateFile) involves more work by the device driver. Device drivers are inclined to do the most work they can do at the initialization/opening in order to optimize subsequent read/write operations. Moreover, many devices may require a long setup. E.g. the "classic" serial driver takes much time to initialize the baudrate prescaler and the handshake signals. Instead, when the device is open and ready, the read and write operations are usually quite fast. But this is just a hint, it depends on the particular driver you are using (traditional COM? USB converter? The drivers are very different). I recommend you an investigation by a profiler.